# Empty values in Google MotionChart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I need to analyze delivery forecasts coming in from suppliers and from database I get a following data array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [delivery_date] => 2012-05-10
            [imported] => 2012-05-10 11:20:37
            [qty] => 114
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [delivery_date] => 2012-05-10
            [imported] => 2012-05-11 11:20:37
            [qty] => 228
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [delivery_date] => 2012-05-10
            [imported] => 2012-05-15 11:20:37
            [qty] => 380
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [delivery_date] => 2012-05-10
            [imported] => 2012-05-16 11:20:37
            [qty] => 380
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [delivery_date] => 2012-05-10
            [imported] => 2012-05-17 11:20:37
            [qty] => 380
        )
)
```

My problem here is that customer is not giving exactly the same forecast every day - and thats normal, but I need to plot out "missing" dates when customer has not predicted that they need x pcs of product on 2012-05-10.

My ideas for possible solution are:

1. somehow mingle with the data array to fill it with empty values for missing "imported" dates
2. somehow configure Google motionchart to display missing values instead of drawing line from point-to-point.

however so far I myself have not succeeded with either of these options:(

Extract from code:
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['motionchart']});

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addRows(<?PHP echo count($data); ?>);
    data.addColumn('string', 'Artikkel@kuupäev');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Imporditud');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Qty, pcs');

    <?PHP
    $jrk=0;

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $date_import = date("Y, m, d",strtotime(substr($row[imported],0,10)." -1 month"));
    echo "data.setValue($jrk, 0, '".$row[delivery_date]."');\n";
        echo "data.setValue($jrk, 1, new Date (".$date_import."));\n";
        echo "data.setValue($jrk, 2, ".$row[qty].");\n";
    $jrk++;         
    } 
    ?> 

    var options = {};
    options['state'] =
'{"yAxisOption":"2","time":"2012-03-12","sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xAxisOption":"_TIME","yZoomedIn":false,"xZoomedDataMax":1331510400000,"yLambda":1,"xZoomedIn":false,"yZoomedDataMin":0,"nonSelectedAlpha":0,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"orderedByY":false,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"duration":{"timeUnit":"D","multiplier":1},"orderedByX":false,"xLambda":1,"colorOption":"_UNICOLOR","yZoomedDataMax":300000,"showTrails":false,"iconType":"LINE","xZoomedDataMin":1304985600000,"iconKeySettings":[],"playDuration":15000};';

    options['width'] = 1200;
    options['height'] = 600;  

    var motionchart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(
       document.getElementById('visualization'));
       motionchart.draw(data, options);
    }
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "issue" has now been solved by Google engineer, so no need to hack it anymore. Line will be braked now in case of missing values.

https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=25